# Declare a member of another class (which takes in a parameter) inside of a class?

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm working with a cpp and .h file for every class, and I'm quite confused about how to use a member of another class which has a constructor with parameters.

MyClass.h:

```
#include "anotherClass.h"
class myClass
{
private:
    int timeN;
    anotherClass Object;        //Following timeN example, it would be declared like so 
public:
    myClass(int timeN);
    ~myClass();
};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass(int timeN) {
    this->timeN = timeN;
    //how to create anotherClass object where waitInt is e.g. 500?
}

myClass::~myClass() {}
```

anotherClass.h:

```
class anotherClass;
{
private:
    int waitInt;
public:
    anotherClass(int waitInt);
    ~anotherClass();
};
```

anotherClass.cpp:

```
#include "anotherClass.h"

anotherClass::anotherClass(int waitInt)
{
    this->waitInt = waitInt;
}

anotherClass::~anotherClass(){}
```

Edit: I can't use initialization lists, I am working on C++98. Therefore it hopefully isn't a duplicate, as all answers for linked post require initialization lists and therefore do not answer my question.

Comment: how do you create an instance of `anotherClass` if it is not inside `myClass` ?

Comment: @user463035818 I don't really understand why anotherClass has to be inside myClass? The header file of anotherClass is included inside myClass. I tried to follow the example here, I just don't know what happens when the constructor takes in something https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-programs/create-an-object-of-a-class-inside-another-class-declaration.aspx

Comment: "I don't really understand why anotherClass has to be inside myClass?" ... you wrote the code, didnt you? What example are you refering to?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass(int argsTimeN) : timeN(argTimeN), Object(500) {
}
```

This is the correct way to initialize class member in C++. Using the `=` operator will make a copy of your object (unless you overloaded the operator).

Any class attributes not initialize that way, will be initialized using the default constructor if it exists

Comment: _"Using the = assignment will call the copy constructor."_ No it won't

Comment: Yes, you're right I wrote that too hastily. my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can also use C++11 feature:

```
class myClass
{
    private:
        //private:
        int timeN;
        anotherClass Object{ 500 };

    public:
        myClass(int _timeN) : timeN(_timeN) { }
        ~myClass() = default;
};
```

if Object does not depend on any constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle this case, depending upon your requirement when developing for more features.

1. Use a pointer for anotherClass inside MyClass
   [pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)
   This way you create a pointer in the header and create an object while you are in the constructor and pass the desired value. You have to remember to delete the pointer in the constructor.

```
#include "anotherClass.h"
class myClass
{
private:
    int timeN;
public:
    myClass(int timeN);
    anotherClass * m_pAnotherClass = nullptr; /* pointer to another class*/
    ~myClass();
};
```

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass(int timeN) {
    this->timeN = timeN;
    //how to create anotherClass object where waitInt is e.g. 500?
    m_pAnotherClass = new anotherClass(500);
}

myClass::~myClass() {
    if(m_pAnotherClass == nullptr)
        delete m_pAnotherClass;  
 }
```

2 Create the object in header and pass the waitInt via a setter function.
This way you can have an object created for anotherClass first and then set the int value in the constructor on myClass. The anotherClass object gets deleted when myClass object is delete.

```
#include "anotherClass.h"
class myClass
{
private:
    int timeN;
    anotherClass Object;        //Following timeN example, it would be declared like so 
public:
    myClass(int timeN);
    ~myClass();
};
```

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass(int timeN) {
    this->timeN = timeN;
    //how to create anotherClass object where waitInt is e.g. 500?
    /* call setWaitInt mehtod and pass the value you want */
    Object.setWaitInt(500);
}

myClass::~myClass() {
}
```

```
{
private:
    int waitInt=0;
public:
    anotherClass();
    setWaitInt(int waitInt);

    ~anotherClass();
};
```

```
#include "anotherClass.h"

anotherClass::anotherClass()
{
}
anotherClass::setWaitInt(int waitInt)
{
    this->waitInt = waitInt;
}
anotherClass::~anotherClass(){}
```